# OrderBy a relationship column of a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing a problem in here. I have 3 tables posts, threads and comments. A thread contain comments and is attached to a post. So, there is a relation between post and threads and a relation between threads and comments. What I need is to sort posts by the latest where if a post has a thread that contains comments then use the comment created_at else if post has no thread attached then use post created at. so I kind of need order by if exists thread.comments.created_at else post.created_at

is this possible?

Comment: Nael, welcome to stackoverflow you can ask about coding, what coding you tried, but this kind of questions  is not welcome here 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261843/questions-that-ask-about-tutorials-or-how-to-do-something-without-showing-code

Comment: @Muath How then should I ask about such problem? I did not know at all how to do it so I don't have a code to show.

Comment: start coding and when you face a problem and you cant solve it, first thing google it, if you didn't find answers you can show us your code and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to accomplish it like this

```
$posts = Post::leftJoin('threads', function($join) {
                $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'threads.post_id');
            })
            ->leftJoin('messages', function($join) {
                $join->on('threads.id', '=', 'messages.thread_id')
                    ->where('messages.id', '=', DB::raw('(select max(messages.id) from messages)'));

            })
            ->orderByRaw('coalesce(messages.created_at, posts.created_at) DESC')
            ->get();
```